# Updating an FTS indexed column returns "Invalid InnoDB FTS Doc ID"

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, full-text-search, mysql-5.6

Environment:

- Ubuntu 12.04 (and 13.04)
- MySQL 5.6.11

I have a table which has a full text index on it (real table has much more columns and rows):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS articles;
CREATE TABLE articles (
  FTS_DOC_ID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id INT NOT NULL ,
  title VARCHAR(200),
  body TEXT,
  UNIQUE KEY (FTS_DOC_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx on articles (title);

INSERT INTO articles(id,title,body) 
  VALUES (9, 'MySQL Tutorial','DBMS stands for DataBase ...');
```

MySQL documentation suggests to create the FTS_DOC_ID (with the right syntax) to prevent a full table rebuild.

So far all is good and I can query using the `MATCH...AGAINST` to use the FTS index. However when I need to update an indexed column:

```
UPDATE articles set title = 'New MySQL Tutorial'  WHERE id=9;
```

I get a:

```
Error code 182, SQL state HY000: Invalid InnoDB FTS Doc ID
```

If I manually take care of this column like this:

```
UPDATE articles a1, (SELECT MAX(FTS_DOC_ID)+1 AS ftsid FROM articles) a2
set title = 'New MySQL Tutorial', FTS_DOC_ID=ftsid  WHERE id=9;
```

Then the update is done. But this is not acceptable because I have several processes in parallel that update this table (though all different rows) and the risk is to get the same `ftsid` in different processes.
Note that updating the `body` column which is not indexed by the FTS index doesn't have this behaviour. I.e.:

```
UPDATE articles set body = 'Info: DBMS stands for DataBase ...' WHERE id=9;
```

successfully update the database.

Is it the expected behaviour? Or is it a bug?

I found a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63689) reported in the MySQL buglist about the opposite case (cannot update a non-fts indexed column but can on an fts indexed one) but not this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is that the `id` column is not indexed. For all intents and purposes, your acting `PRIMARY KEY` is `FTS_DOC_ID` since it is the only unique key present without a `PRIMARY KEY` definition.

Since `id` is not indexed, I could see mysqld wanting to do a full table scan to fulfill the query. You should want to create a UNIQUE KEY on `id` as well if you intend on having two different unique keys and having two different references to one row.

Note that `FTS_DOC_ID` has the auto_increment attribute. There is no need to increment it manually, like you did with

```
UPDATE articles a1, (SELECT MAX(FTS_DOC_ID)+1 AS ftsid FROM articles) a2
set title = 'New MySQL Tutorial', FTS_DOC_ID=ftsid  WHERE id=9;
```

In fact, by doing this, you are actually taking the `FTS_DOC_ID` and changing it on `id`.

Looking back at your first query

```
UPDATE articles set title = 'New MySQL Tutorial'  WHERE id=9;
```

Why would this be a problem (and essentially a bug) ? Again, this goes back to `id` not being indexed.

When a column is not indexed, the [Clustered Index of the table (where the PRIMARY KEY resides)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html) is unaware of the presence of `id`. How is this so?

According to [the Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672327651)

[image: oxcnd]

Chapter 12 Pages 260,261 (Subheading Secondary Indexes) says the following:

> What about other indexes? How are they structured, and what is their
>   relationship with the data found in the clustered index?
>
> These additional indexes are know as "secondary indexes," and you can
>   create as many of them as you need for an InnoDB table. Because our
>   sample table schema definition requests an index on the last_name
>   column, InnoDB creates one secondary index on this value.Each entry in
>   the secondary index contains the primary key value from the clustered
>   index,thereby facilitating linkage back to the data.

### Your First Query

Since `id` is not indexed your first update failed. MySQL (eh Oracle) should have caught this problem. So, it is a bug.

### Your Second Query

The update works because you accessed the Clustered Index indirectly by trying to manually update the `FTS_DOC_ID` column.

### Your Third Query

It worked because you accessed no indexes at all, neither on `id` nor on `body`. In that instance, a full table scan would easily fulfill this request.

### Epilogue

If I were you, I would report this as a bug ASAP because MySQL 5.6's FULLTEXT indexing for InnoDB is what people want these days and query plans should be accommodating it with WHERE clauses whether accessing with the Clustered index or not.

Comment: Thank you. Bug reported (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69412). I needed the AUTO_INCREMENT on FTS_DOC_ID because it wouldn't allow me to create a PRIMARY KEY on it (can't recall the exact issue there but found from another post/forum to do that :) )